# c error: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]

Tags: c

I keep getting the error "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]" when I try to compile my code. I'm not sure what's going on because I've checked that everything matches the variable type int*.

```
int main(void) {

    int* sunkList, newSunkList;
    char*** shipArray;

    sunkList=createSunkList(nShips);
    newSunkList=updateSunkList(sunkList, shipArray);

    return 0;
}
```

newSunkList=updateSunkList(sunkList, shipArray) is where the error is.

```
int* createSunkList(int nShips);
{
    int i;
    int* result=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*nShips);
    for(i=0;i<nShips;i++)
        result[i]=1;

    return result;
}

int* updateSunkList(int* sunkList, char*** shipArray)
{
    char** temp;
    int i,j,k,a=0;

    for(k=0;k<nShips;k++)
    {
        temp=shipArray[k];
        for(i=0;i<row;i++)
        {
                for(j=0;j<col;j++)
                {
                    if(temp[i][j] = 'S')
                        a=1; /* If 'S' is found then a turns to 1 */
                }
        }

        if(a==0) /* If a==0 then no 'S' has been found so the ship has sunk */
            sunkList[k]=0;  
    }

    return sunkList;
}
```

Comment: `int* sunkList, newSunkList;` will declare `sunkList` as an integer pointer and `newSunkList` as an `int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the line

```
    int* sunkList, newSunkList;
```

declares `sunkList` as an integer pointer (`int *`) and `newSunkList` as a normal `int`, thus the warning:

```
warning: assignment to ‘int’ from ‘int *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

to fix the error you should declare the two variables as follows:

```
int *sunkList, *newSunkList;
```

or:

```
int *sunkList;
int *newSunkList;
```